# When i run docker " Docker Desktop - Unexpected WSL error " this kind of error throw

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

[When i Run docker i this kind of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ3rm.png)

I want to run docker desktop

I have installed the Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b in my windows PC. I am using Windows 10 Pro. I have tried the very basic docker command but it is not working. I have also run the docker as administrator. Getting the below error always

Comment: have you tried: ```wsl --unregister docker-desktop``` command ?